# How do I stop Visual Studio Code from autofilling in the parameter names when I write a function?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image: This is what I am talking about. In this example I have a object of the class Politician who has a function. When I type in the function it autofills the parameters]

How do I stop Visual Studio code from doing this? I have inlay parameter names disabled in the settings but it still will auto populate the parameter names.

This is VS code 1.71.0 with Java 8 Update 341

Comment: After searching, the parameters related to this function switch were not found. So if you want to turn it off, I guess you'll have to disable the *[Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://imgur.com/C7KiqIn)* extension, but that would result in losing a lot of smart suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable this with `java.completion.guessMethodArguments` in the VS code settings.

[image: The setting in VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with the different auto suggestions mode using the setttings: ->Text-Editor->Suggestions. Maybe one setup could be a good workaround.